# 3-side punched steel channel (strut), image in the post - can't find any equivalents

Tags: electrical, conduit, steel, product-recommendation

I'm looking to install a hoist system mounted to garage ceiling. I was originally going to attach some 2x4s to the ceiling joists and attach pulleys to those, but then decided to go with steel channels isntead. What I'm looking for is something like this: 
[image: 3-side-punched-strut]
It's 12 gauge steel (US, about 2.5mm) with holes on 3 sides and 1 side open.

All the home centers around seem to be carrying something similar, but without holes on the sides - only on the top. Such channels cost like $25-35/10ft. `Kindorf` looks to be the only manufacturer that I've seen so far making these struts with holes punched on all 3 sides which is so convenient for many applications, but theirs was like $100+/10ft when I saw it available.

Looking for links/brand names/keywords to use in a search/etc.

Comment: Zoro Tools is selling 8 foot lengths of strut channel for $25 plus modest shipping fee. https://www.ebay.com/c/1839450070

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: You might find that the Unistrut channel nuts or other specialty hardware give you a way to attach to the track without the holes on the sides.

Comment: Try companies that sell storage products...like warehouse shelving systems, etc.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate but I liked this type specifically for the ability to just put bolts in any place I like. I know there are those spring nuts, etc. But I'm not even sure those can hold lateral loads or only "pull-out" loads.

Comment: @GregNickoloff good suggestion!

Comment: @MichaelKaras That one only has holes on one side, not all three. That's my problem, as soon as you find one that's punched on 3 sides - it costs more than $100 / 10ft.

Comment: @DanielGriscom this is not a shopping question. I'm looking for a product, which to me seems like a pretty basic construction material - a steel "C-shaped beam" with holes punched in all 3 sides. I don't need an electrical channel or any accessories for it - Just the steel beam with holes, so that I didn't have to drill a gazillion of them myself.

Comment: You can easily mount it using the one set of holes. Then use the proper slide in mount point plates. You can also easily drill what few holes you would need from the sides.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I guess I'll have to resort to drilling. I was just hoping that there was a known source of this rather simple construction material. And it does exist, they simply charge 4 times the price for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That stuff is called Unistrut.   Comes in a variety of configurations.   Keep in mind the normal way to attach to it is put special clips with springs that latch into those tucked-in grooves.  They're not just for strength.

When you see stupid pricing on the Internet, that's the "I don't want to sell it" price, or to be more precise, the "I don't want to ship it" price.  They are trolling for noobs who don't know or care what normal prices are, and will pay whatever.  Anything like that - heavy and cheap - should be sourced locally.  If that means you need to skill up on procurement, then definitely do that.  Grainger, lumber yards, local metal supply, electrical supply houses, cast a wide net.

Comment: I've really been struggling to figure out how to procure strut channel fittings.  Is Grainger the kind of place you can walk into and shop their stock?  I thought it was more like you place an order and pick it up there, which leads to the "stupid pricing" problem.  Graybar, Grainger, Unistrut service locations... they all seem to not be open for browsing, and their web-listed prices are often insane (my favorite was $18,000+ for 100 post bases).

Answer (score 3):

The price you see online from a construction supply companies is often a "list price" that is above what a contractor actually pays, so the contractors customers can't easily shop their prices.

Kindorf B-995-10 (sku 785991758801 or Powerstrut ps200 h3) isn't often used, and probably would only be stocked by a construction supply company. Often electrical and hvac vendors actually source strut locally from those companies due to difficult shipping. In the US you might be able to find a stocking vendor at [ABB/Thomas & Betts](http://www-public.tnb.com/ps/dls/) vendor search webpage if you enter your zip code and B-995-10.